# What is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

What is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$?

Remarks:

(1) I think it is clear that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ is an integral domain;  indeed, $x^2+y^2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ is irreducible (by considerations of degrees) hence prime.

(2) The field of fractions of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(t)$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96400/mathbbqx-y-langle-x2y2-1-rangle-is-an-integral-domain-and-its-field) and also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739097/characterizing-the-field-of-fractions-of-mathbb-qx-y-x2y2-1).

Comment: Is your question : "Is ... an already known field" ?

Comment: Please, what is your definition of "an already known field"? I am guessing that the field of fractions is something like $R(t)$, where $R$ is an algebraic field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$; but I may be wrong.

Comment: $\mathbb Q(x,y)=\mathbb Q(\frac xy,y)=\mathbb Q(\frac xy)(y)=\mathbb Q(i)(y)$ since $(\frac xy)^2+1=0$

Comment: Very nice comment, @user26857. The same idea proves that the normalization  of  $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ is $\mathbb C|y]$. But this is very strange (to me): it says that the normalization of the real "conic" $\operatorname {Spec}\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2) $ is the affine line $\mathbb A^1_\mathbb C=\operatorname {Spec}\mathbb{C}[y]$. Do I remember correctly that you already wrote something about this normalization ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Do you mean about the normalization of the quotient rings $\mathbb Q[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$ and/or $\mathbb R[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$ ?

Comment: Dear @user26857,  yes exactly: The normalization of $A=\mathbb R[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$ is $\mathbb C[Y]$. I computed this long ago and I remember being quite amazed by  the answer . Everything hangs together beautifully: the fraction field $\mathbb R(i)(Y)$, which you calculated,  of $A$ is the same as that of its normalization $\overline A=\mathbb C[Y]$. By the way, I hope you will soon return to this site, so that we can again enjoy your beautifully crisp and elegant answers !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First do the substitution $x'=x/y$. Then the equation $x^2+y^2=0$ transforms to $x'^2+1=0$. Hence we are looking at the (isomorphic) field $\text{Frac}(\mathbb Q[x',y]/(x'^2+1))$.

This is just $\mathbb Q(i)(y)$.